# How to solve optimization problem involving a trace of inverse of a matrix with multiple variables?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let the matrix be:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a_1^T X a_1 & a_2^TXa_2\\ a_3^TXa_3 & a_4^TXa_4 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $a_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to minimize the trace of inverse of this matrix so:

$$\min_{X} \qquad \frac{a_1^TXa_1+a_4^TXa^4}{a_1^TXa_1 a^T_4Xa_4-a_2^TXa_2 a_3^T X a_3}$$
$$\text{subject to:} \qquad \text{trace}(X) = 1$$
$$\text{and} \qquad   X \succeq 0$$

Comment: Are you sure you can't reformulate it to some easier form?

Comment: In the numerator I can probably have something like $(a_1+a_4)^T X (a_1+ a_4)$. On the denominator, I am trying to figure it out. Will probably be in the for of $X^T X$ but im not sure what exactly.

Comment: Can you confirm that $X$ a **symmetrical** $n \times n$ matrix ?

Comment: Yes it is symmetrical n by n matrix. @JeanMarie

Answer (score 0):

If $n>4$ and the $a$s are linearly indepedent, I don't see why a minimum exists.

Pick an orthogonal basis $\{b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, \ldots\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the first four basis vectors span the same space as the $a$s, and the rest span the orthogonal complement. Pick $b_3$ and $b_4$ so that they are orthogonal to $a_1$ and $a_4$.

Now set $X$ to be the matrix whose eigenvectors are the $b_i$s, where the corresponding eigenvalues are
$$\lambda_i = \begin{cases} \epsilon^3, &i=1,2\\
\epsilon^2, &i=3,4\\
\frac{1-2\epsilon^3-2\epsilon^2}{n-4}, &i>4.\end{cases}
$$

For sufficiently small $\epsilon$, your objective function is negative with arbitrarily large magnitude.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand how you did the eigenvalue decomposition of the matrix. Could you explain a bit on that?